# What is meant by a "general linear form"?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I've been reading some papers lately on the topic of generic initial ideals and related stuff, and here and there the concept of a "general linear form" (or general quadric, quintic, etc.) comes up. This seems to have some special meaning in the context, but I can't figure out what it is, and I can't find any definition in any of the sources I'm reading or when I google. I know what a linear form is, but what does it mean that it's general? I'm new to the subject and self studying so I don't have anyone to ask.

For example, in M.L. Green's "Generic Initial Ideals" from *6 Lectures on Commutative algebra*, say Proposition 2.7, he talks about general linear forms.

I've seen general forms talked about in reference to some Zariski open set, like in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.11836.pdf), at the end of the first page, and I'm missing what that means. Can anyone clarify for me?

Comment: Typically "form" means homogenous polynomial so a linear form would be a homogenous polynomial of degree one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I know what a form is and what a linear form is, I'm just not sure what it means when they say a "general" linear form. It seems like it means something more than "arbitrary" in this context which is how I usually see the word general being used.

Answer (score 3):

A linear form on a vector space $V$ is an element of $V^*$. Usually, when people say that something holds for a general linear form they mean that there is some Zariski-open set $U\subset V^*$ such that the statement holds for all elements of $U$. For example, a general linear form is non-zero. This extends to other contexts as soon as you have the Zariski topology on the space of your objects. As another example, it is true that a general plane cubic curve is smooth, in the sense that for a general choice of coefficients of the curve's equation the curve is smooth.

Comment: Okay thank you! So if we're talking about a general linear form and not any specific property holding for it, does that just mean it's a linear form that's non-zero? Or does the general form have any inherent properties in and of itself? Sorry if that question doesn't make sense, I'm just trying to understand haha

Comment: @beep27 General basically means "almost any" in sone precise sense. Which forms are not good enough for you depends on the question. For example, a general linear form is not zero on a given vector, but the set of forms that do vanish on said vector heavily depends on the vector.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! I think I'm starting to understand it better now